# Select an item from the drop-down list

Tags: c#

Good morning.
I can not select an item from the drop-down list.

[image: drpp-down]

Did the following:

1) I entered the text

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById ("Advert_category_id").InnerText = "Wedding / Event Services";
```

2) Set the value using the following commands, in different sequences, as soon as not twisted.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").InvokeMember("onchange");
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").InvokeMember("submit");
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").InvokeMember ("value", "84");
```

The problem is that this code selects the option I need, but it does not appear in the field. Those. Only when you click on the field, after executing the code, you can see that the desired option is selected. But this approach is also not true, because
The following drop-down list named SUB CATEGORY does not load the required data (the data remains with the category selected by default - Professional)
3. I tried to experiment with different id-shniki. Nothing helps :(

The site itself https://list.asiandirectoryapp.com/advert/create
(You must register to view)
I made the second ack,
That would not waste time for registration
fovogaze@p33.org
qwerty123
The code of interest

```html
 <div style="display:none"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="Advert_city_id">City</label><select class="form-control" name="Advert[city_id]" id="Advert_city_id">
    </select><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_city_id_em_" style="display:none"></div></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="Advert_category_id">Category <span class="required">*</span></label><select class="form-control" name="Advert[category_id]" id="Advert_category_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="35">Beauty, Health &amp; Fitness</option>
    <option value="19">Education</option>
    <option value="21">Entertainment</option>
    <option value="27">Food, Drink &amp; Sweet Centres</option>
    <option value="39">Home Services</option>
    <option value="116">Jobs/Careers</option>
    <option value="43">Motoring</option>
    <option value="50">Other Services</option>
    <option value="1">Professional</option>
    <option value="51">Property Improvements</option>
    <option value="84">Wedding/Event Services</option>
    <option value="117">Whats On Guide</option>
    </select><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_category_id_em_" style="display:none"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="Advert_categoryList">Sub category <span class="required">*</span></label><select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="Advert[categoryList][]" id="Advert_categoryList">
    <option value="2">Accountants</option>
    <option value="4">Claims</option>
    <option value="123">Clothing Manufacturers</option>
    <option value="6">Estate &amp; Letting Agents</option>
    <option value="7">Finance/Mortgages</option>
    <option value="8">Graphic &amp; Web Design</option>
    <option value="9">Immigration</option>
    <option value="10">Information Technology</option>
    <option value="11">Insurance</option>
    <option value="13">Mobile Apps - Mobile Phones</option>
    <option value="14">Online Marketing/ SEO</option>
    <option value="18">Print</option>
    <option value="15">Retail and Wholesale</option>
    <option value="16">Solicitors - Lawyers</option>
    <option value="17">Travel Agents</option>
    </select><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_categoryList_em_" style="display:none"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="Advert_name">Company Name <span class="required">*</span></label><input class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" name="Advert[name]" id="Advert_name" type="text" maxlength="100" /><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_name_em_" style="display:none"></div></div>
```

P.S. I can fill out all the fields, press the buttons the same way, but with the drop-down list the trouble. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem but I chose to solve it by simply invoking a client-side javascript (with a parameter) that handles the manipulation of the dom objects.

I found that this way I can separate code too, keeping dom handling in the JS and application-code in the winforms. Itll also allow you to leverage any functionality provided by e.g. jQuery plugins wrapping the select.

It could look like this (not tested):

```
Object[] objArray = new Object[2];
        objArray[0] = selectorID;
        objArray[1] = valueToSet;
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetSelector", objArray);
```

and in the client side:

```
function SetSelector(selectorID, valueToSet){
  $('#'+selectorID).val(valueToSet); //or any function you'd like
}
```